# Electron version v14 to v15 update Problem

Tags: authentication, cookies, request, electron

I have the following problem and now after several days still can not solve it.

I am upgrading an Electron app from version 12 to version 22. The app is there to make certain data packages of our customer more manageable. I have already managed to update the app to version 22, but there is still an error that occurred when updating from version 14 to version 15.

To log in to the app, the external login page of our customer opens in a second window of the app. The login is handled there. I only get back whether the login was successful or not. Afterwards it is checked if the file packages are up to date or if updates are available ect.

So far, everything works fine. But from version 14 to version 15 of Electron there is a problem. The login works, but the following query for updates ect. fails. This query is only possible if you are logged in.

In the Developer Tools I see that I get redirected from request url to the login page. As far as I understand, the Problem is related to the cookies. As if the query would not have access to the cookies of the successful login. But when I look at the breaking changes of version 15 I don't find anything about it.

Does anyone know what the problem could be or how I could fix it?

Comment: did you check the [Releases](https://releases.electronjs.org/releases/stable?version=15&page=12&limit=2) pages?

Comment: Hi, yes I checked the page.